# Executing linq lamda expression as parameter in System.Reflection Invoke Method calling

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, system.reflection

I'm trying to execute My GetSingleAsync method which comes with system reflection. But ı need to execute linq query when I'm invoking this method, in my researches ı mostly saw just single parameters,but ı need to execute linq expression in this method call.

Here is what I'm trying to get when ı execute:

`var data = await repository.GetSingleAsync(record => record.date == StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));`

Here is my current code try, i need to execute **record => record.date == StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")** linq in question mark part:

```
dynamic repository = Activator.CreateInstance(RepositoryType);
 
MethodInfo GetSingleAsync = RepositoryType.GetMethod("GetSingleAsync");

var model = GetSingleAsync.Invoke(repository, ??);      //need help in question mark?
```

Comment: How would you know that the entity type in `RepositoryType` would contain a `date` property?  Do all your entity types have that date property?  If not, this question doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: `record.date == StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` is a single parameter.  Have you tried passing this as the first parameter in the `Invoke` ?

Comment: Yes, it is. it is base MongoDb repository entity, it has date, documentName, and Id properties in it. I just didn't share the all method to keep the question simpler @Kirk Woll

Comment: As a string ? @Neil

Comment: No, it's an expression.

Comment: no, unfortunately its not possible cause record and StartDate is not declared.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to look at the parameters of `GetSingleAsync`. Assuming the parameter needs to be of type `Func<T,bool>` then you need:

```
Func<T,bool> predicate = rec => rec.Property == someValue;
```

Your parameter is then

```
var model = GetSingleAsync.Invoke(repository, new []{ predicate });
```

Update:
If you do not want to depend on some Type T you can construct your predicate using Expression API:

```
    public static object SomePredicate(Type recordType, string propertyName, Expression comparisonValue) {
            var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(recordType);
            var propertyExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExpression, propertyName);
            var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Equal(propertyExpression, comparisonValue), parameterExpression);
            return lambdaExpression.Compile();
        }
```

You can then construct your predicates like so (if you have a type Repository with integer Property Record):

```
var somePredicate = SomePredicate(typeof(Repository), nameof(Repository.Record), Expression.Constant(5));
```

Comment: If ı didnt miss something, ı need to give my model Class as a  T parameter in delegation. So it will spoil my generic class work. But if it accept the type which ı create from Class Assembly Name, it will work. I'll be updating...

Comment: I just added the T. Could you provide the signature of GetSingleAsync? Or elaborate on what you see as issue...